# Windows 10 unreadable after converting from MBR to GPT

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, mbr, gpt

I tried converting my system disk from MBR to UEFI with gptgen. It said it was successful but now it won't boot back in. Currently in UEFI boot.

Don't have enough Rep to post images but basically fdisk outputs my original windows partitions as Microsoft basic data. Gdisk claims to have found a valid GPT with protective MBR.

I *don't* have any backups. T.T

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have no backups there isn't a solution to your problem

Comment: Perhaps any recovery tools I can use?

Comment: They won't reverse the damage GPTgen has done

Comment: Seems to me like the issue is with the bootloader, not the filesystem. If this is the case, quick! grab your files before you mess something up! Boot to a linux live cd and copy your files to an external drive or something. As for the bootloader, have you tried switching to legacy? GPT is likely not UEFI-compatible, and even then, i'm not sure how that works when booting to a UEFI OS

Comment: @Blaine I believe GPT is UEFI-compatible. The windows 10 install media even allows you to choose between GPT or MBR.

Comment: Ramhound, it's possible to install an EFI-mode boot loader after an MBR-to-GPT conversion, which would restore bootability *if* the computer has EFI/UEFI firmware. It's also possible to reverse the conversion (to do a [GPT-to-MBR conversion](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#gpt2mbr)) and to then fix the BIOS-mode boot loader. These tasks are not trivial, but the situation isn't nearly as hopeless as you suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it. I was correct to assume that data had just been untouched. I just had to modify the boot partition so that it was compatible with my new UEFI.

I followed the resources available here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14286.converting-windows-bios-installation-to-uefi.aspx